# remove each third element in PowerShell array

Tags: string, powershell

I have very long string which I copy and paste from external program to PowerShell.
After splitting it (

> $variable=$variable.split("`n")

) I received array from which i Want remove every third element.
What is most convenient way of accomplishing it?
I thought about loop from

> 0 to $variable.lenght()-1

and check if i can be divided by three, but maybe there is other way?

Answer (score 2):

If you need to remove values any 3 positions (0-based: 2,5,8,11,14 and so on)  in the array use something like this:

```
$newArray = @()
0..($variable.length) | % {
    if ((($_+1) % 3 ) -ne 0) {
        $newArray += $variable[$_]
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

$new=for ($i=2;$i -lt $array.count;$i+=3) {$array[$i]}

This will start at the 3rd element and get every third. Pipelined output is saved to $new.

Comment: I decided to go back and double check. Using an array with 100 members running my code took 1.0246ms. Using the earlier ForEach example took 12.8752ms. Both ways work and for small arrays the performance difference is negligible.

Answer (score 1):

```
$new_variable = $variable | foreach {$i=1} {if ($i++ %3){$_}}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$i = 0
$variable = $variable.split("`n") | ? {++$i % 3}
```

Answer (score 0):

Or

```
0..($variable.count-1) | foreach { if($_%3) {$variable[$_]} }
```